# Using Zapfdingbats with jsPDf

Tags: fonts, jspdf

I'm trying to add a checkmark as text to a pdf document with jsPDf and the built-in Zapfdingbats font, but I'm running into issues. What is the correct way to access the glyphs in this font?

```
doc.setFont("Zapfdingbats");
doc.setFontStyle("normal");
doc.text("\u2714", 20, 20, null, null, "left");
```

When I use the above and render the pdf in an iframe, I get an error message via an alert message saying "Error in function Object.F (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:26266:81): Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."

Note: I'm using this in my react app using create-react-app.

When I try:

```
doc.text(btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent("\u2714"))), 20, 20, null, null, "left");
```

I get the checkmark but also three additional symbols that I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkmark glyph is mapped to "4"

```
doc.text("4", xPosition, yPosition, null, null, "left");
```

Answer (score 1):

Question regarding the answer:  how did you know that checkmark is mapped to "4"?  I am trying to use the trademark (TM) in Symbol font, but have not figured out how to do it yet. 
I was able to use your answer above to put a checkmark where I want the TM. If I can find the correct mapping to the Symbol font, it should work. (I have tried "\u2122", but it came out like py!" in the file.)

Comment: by experimenting. I believe the glyphs are mapped to single characters. You can use "doc.text("abcdefg...") and each letter is mapped to a different glyph. I'm not seeing the trademark symbol in the symbol font after experimenting, but if you only need the letters "TM" you could accomplish that with text, right? Btw, welcome to StackOverflow! FYI, it's better to use comments to ask a follow-up question rather than posting an answer when not intending to answer the original poster's question.

Comment: As follow up, from what I've learned, there is no TM in the fonts embedded in Acrobat PDF.  I could have just used a smaller size tm, but the placement was driving me nuts. In the end, it turned out that I had to upgrade my version of jspdf. It didn't automatically get upgraded when I installed jspdf-autotable as I thought it would. After running npm to update it, the TM was correct on the download file.

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution! I'm linking your other question that shows additional mappings beyond the single characters I originally thought https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379828/what-is-the-mapping-of-zaptdingbats-and-symbols-in-jspdf