# What is the mapping of ZaptDingBats and Symbols in jsPDF?

Tags: fonts, symbols, jspdf

I am trying to use the TM in the Symbols font,  but not sure how to do it - I searched around here and found this similar question for the checkmark in ZaptDingBats font. The answer to this related question mentions that the checkmark is mapped as 4...this leads me to my question of how do we know what the mapping is?

[Using Zapfdingbats with jsPDf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333857/using-zapfdingbats-with-jspdf)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the JS octal sequence \u2122 and jsPDF will output the TM symbol. See [this list](https://brajeshwar.me/entities/) for more sequences. [Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2tg5.jpg) of output.

```
doc.text(50, 30, 'Trademark symbol is \u2122')
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blestab/deLrhg1o/) that saves the PDF and the TM symbol is still visible. Can you paste your code into a fiddle so we can see what you are getting.

PS: You might want to fix your post heading to "...Symbols in jspdf?" :)

Comment: Thank you for the chart, unfortunately, the saved pdf is still not displaying the TM correctly. I now get what looks like py!"..... I will be researching more on this task.   As for editing the heading, I am new user and cannot edit it.

Comment: I have the code in jsFiddle, but do not know how to make it public. In case it already is, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/lsimpson/yrk2ofxt/71/               In this example code, it works for me.  The issue I was having was that I thought I needed to remove the 'TM' in the original value and replace it.  I had didParseCell to remove the TM and then didDrawCell to add Symbol font.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your fiddle is accessible. 

Glad to know the suggestion worked. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers